# How to redirect Wordpress permalinks on the admin panel to a completely unique structure?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working with the WP-API plugin using Wordpress and I am trying to figure out how I can adjust the permalink structure to point to my client side application that is consuming the API rather than pointing to the internal routing of Wordpress.

I want the user to create a page and be able to view it in my client side application, rather than on the server side.

So as an example, if I create a new page / post in my Wordpress Admin, I get the following Permalink URL provided after publish:

`127.0.0.1/wordpress/example-test-post/`

I want the link to point to my client side application (which has no understanding of Wordpress and is completely silo'd from WP):

`127.0.0.1/front-end/#/pages/example-test-post/`

Is this possible without diving into the deep internals of WP?

I suppose another solution would be to have my Wordpress theme perform a redirect over to the client side application, but that seems inefficient.

Comment: Permslinks editor in settings allows for a custom structure.

Comment: It allows it if you use Wordpress as the reference, I am using a client side application that is completely removed from Wordpress. Wordpress is only operating as a JSON API in my application, it does not render any views.

Answer (score 0):

The `wp_redirect` function has resolved the issue for me, it's documentation can be found [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect)

I am now forcing a redirect from:

`127.0.0.1/wordpress/example-test-post/`

to:

`127.0.0.1/front-end/#/pages/example-test-post/`